# Append to an environment variable without overwriting values from .env file

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv

Assuming the `.env` file is loaded before execution, how can you append to it without overriding it?

```
DEBUG=True
FOO=BAR
PYTHONPATH="/Users/James/project/"
```

The above file would (?) override it, and that would be bad. I could put it in  `.bash_profile` or `.profile`, but that's not consistent with what I have now, and I only want to set it for the current `virtualenv` too.

I don't think this makes any difference, but I'm using Mac OS X (the tutorial I was using was multi-platform)

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to add a couple environment variables temporarily? It sounds like you just want to `export DEBUG=True`. This will set the DEBUG variable only for the current shell and it's children.

Comment: @user1794469 Is that possible in the .env file? I want to append to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: It shoudl, you just add the current: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/James/project` or `export PYTHONPATH=/Users/James/project:$PYTHONPATH` depending on which path you want search first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you most likely want to do is export the variables you are interested in. The following will make the variable available to the current shell and any sub-processes it creates:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/James/project
```

Here a process that uses `PYTHONPATH` will first search the existing path for its target and if not found, try the `/Users/James/project`. If you wanted to overide some existing path, you could add the new path first:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/James/project:$PYTHONPATH
```

In either case, other shells will not see the variable (and obviously closing the shell will make the variable unaccessible).